# How to use bytesio in functions that only support path?

Tags: python, file, pipe, bytesio

The function I use accepts only one path parameter. But the file data is in memory. It's too slow to open it after save. Is there any way to wrap bytesio into a path then i can pass it to the function?

Comment: Use `m.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: if the function accepts file handle as input then you can pass the `io.bytes` object to it directly, otherwise your only option is to modify whatever function you are calling to accept a file handle, instead of a path

Comment: try passing a file handle with `'rb'` instead of the file path to your function, if it accepts it then you can pass the `io.bytes` object instead.